# Surveying mostly the same population over time: t test appropriate?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I'm looking to run a satisfaction survey on a population of about 100 subjects. My response rate is about 70%, and I plan to survey repeatedly, once a month, for a year.

How can I test statistical significance in a change to satisfaction month over month? The respondents are mostly the same every month but there is random variation of who responds and who does not.

Should this be a hierarchical model with a random effect for respondent, to avoid the issue of the error terms between individuals being correlated?

I assumed something like:

`y ~ month + (1 + respondent)`

I could then run simulations for each month to compute confidence intervals and see which months there are significant changes between.